# Objective C: @property(retain) doesn't call retain?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, properties, retain, retaincount

I was trying to track a strage memory allocation bug so I overrode the retain and release methods of my class. I noticed that when assigning an instance of this class to a property of another, the retain count of the object increased, but my redefined retain was never called.

How can this be possible? Are (retain) properties retaining the object without calling retain?

Answer (score 3):

In my machine, the overridden `retain` was called. (I'm using 10.6.4. I checked this both on GCC 4.2.1 and clang 1.5.) 
Could you post your code?

Internally, the synthesized setter for a `retain` property uses `objc_setProperty`, the source code of which is available [here](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437.1/runtime/Accessors.subproj/objc-accessors.m).
As you see, eventually it calls `[newObject retain]` when the property uses `retain`.

Comment: I'll try to post a simple example later, as the code where I noticed this behavior is part of a large app. I forgot to mention that this was on an iPhone app, using the 3.2 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Is garbage collection turned on? I don't believe `retain` is called under GC.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't use self (self.*yourproperty*), it won't increase the retain count.

Comment: Correct, if you assign a value to the iVar _someVar = a; then the memory management token in the property is ignored.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't be surprised if synthesized properties would modify the retain count without calling retain or release.